# Injecting EJB into Rest Exception Handler

Tags: rest, ejb, apache-tomee

I'm trying to inject a local `@Stateless` EJB into a Rest exception handler but getting the following error.

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [Test] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [Test].
```

The maven Web project is running on Apache-tomee-1.7.1-jaxrs.

The EJB:

```
@Stateless(name = "Test")
public class Test {

    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

}
```

The Exception handler which from my understanding I must treat as a client to the EJB.

```
@Provider
public class TestExceptionHandler implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {

    @Context
    HttpServletRequest request;

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Throwable throwable) {

        InitialContext context;
        try {
            context = new InitialContext();
            Test test = (Test) context.lookup("Test");
            test.sayHello();

        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }        


        return Response.ok().build();
    }    

}
```

I have also tried to do the following for the lookup: `context.lookup("java:comp/env/Test");`

The http://openejb.apache.org/jndi-names.html documentation is very difficult to understand.
Also tried the following which was my first attempt. http://blog.iadvise.eu/2015/06/01/jee-using-ejb-and-context-annotations-in-a-jax-rs-provider-class/

Am I missing any configuration in the tomee server or in my code?

Answer (score 0):

The `java:comp/env` namespace is for the EJB *references*, not EJBs.  You have not declared an EJB reference anywhere.

It's probably easiest to directly look up the EJB using `lookup("java:module/Test")` (assuming the EJB is packaged in the war, otherwise, `java:app/ejbmodname/Test`) because JAX-RS does not support EE injection by default.  To declare an EJB reference, you would need to make the provider class an EJB itself or a CDI class (add beans.xml to the module), and then declare a field as `@EJB(name="Test") Test myBean;`.

Comment: Hi bkail, beans.xml file has been included from the beginning, all other injections work. I have tried making the provider a stateless bean but still no result, also include the EJB field plus its name as "Test" but still nothing.  Tried the "java:module/Test" approach but got the error: Unable to find [module]

Comment: @Rentius2407 Did you add the `@EJB`?  You're otherwise not using any EE injection.  Also, I'm not sure why `java:module` doesn't work; perhaps it's a configuration issue in your application server.

Comment: I have tried both the `@Inject` and `@EJB`. I'm using Apache-tomee-1.7.1-jaxrs as my server.

Comment: Tomee is using CXF as the rest implementation. In short I want to inject a `EJB` into a `@Provider`.

Comment: If you tried `@EJB`/`@Inject`, then I'm out of ideas, sorry.